# React Native app crashes without any error log

Tags: crash, react-native

React Native app crashing without any error log. No output on "`react-native log-android`" terminal, no red screen with error, Android emulator just crashes. Tried running with Expo, again crashes with no error

Happens when working with `TextInput`. I have some ideas how I can fix the code, but want to understand why is app crashing without error log and making debugging much more difficult?

Comment: Can you check on ios device?

Comment: can you please share the code where you are getting this issue?

Answer (score 55):

my bug was fixed by deleting the build folder(inside android/app) and running

```sh
npx react-native run-android
```

Comment: This is what worked for me... I have the command "yarn android" to build, but had to delete android/app/build.

Comment: Worked for me too, I got crashes after installing an npm package, but this method fixed that

Comment: deleting build folder gave me out of memory error
Now fixing that error

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil Run `./gradlew clean ` in the android folder

Comment: can you explain more . where is the android/app located

Comment: in the root folder

Comment: no answers are accepted as of now

Comment: did not work for me. I am still getting this and i tried the `./gradlew clean` and the build delete. Also a npm install.

Answer (score 44):

Run adb logcat

You can find your app name in your package.json, under the name field.

Also when looking for errors specifically dealing with react native, try running

`adb logcat | grep 'redbox'`

This way you don't have to scan the entire logfile.

Or try the method shown in [this article](https://medium.com/@taufiq_ibrahim/using-adb-logcat-for-react-native-debugging-38256bda007c):

> Run `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V` in a terminal to see your Android app's logs.

Comment: Thnx i was able to find about, why android app was crashing

Comment: I am fased issue with your command.                                                                      
'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: @BaiMaoli "grep" is a Linux command. The equivalent would be "findstr" in windows.

Comment: to see the logs when using zsh use `adb logcat '*:S' ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`

Answer (score 15):

I was running an Android Project on my Linux PC, then I have made some changes on it in a MacOS PC, and when I git pulled de project back to Linux I faced that crashes

inside the `android` folder, just run:

```sh
./gradlew clean
```

and then try to run it again.

Comment: This saved me. Thank you.

Comment: Saved me too. Thank you

Comment: but i am using VS code should it will work in VS code also.

Answer (score 13):

In case none of these work, don't hesitate to just filter on Warning or Higher as sometimes there will be a low level error that will not be caught by the RN filters.

I was only able to find my issue(s) with the following:

```
adb logcat '*:W'.
```

Answer (score 7):

In case react native app crashes without an error message checking the problem in Android Studio's Logcat works perfect. But don't forget to create a filter with your package name.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open Logcat
3. Click on "Edit Filter Configuration" in the right top of the logcat screen
4. Fill in your criteria (don't forget package name)
5. Run you react native project on an android device or emulator

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This may be because SOLoader is absent.

Ensure

`implementation'com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.9.0+'`

is added under dependencies in android/app/build.gradlle

clean your build
`cd android`
`./gradlew clean`

Try bundling
`./gradlew bundleRelease`

Exit android folder
`cd ../`

Try running
`npx react-native run-android --variant=release`

Answer (score 3):

My RN App works correctly before, suddenly one day it does not work, keeps crashing without error log. All I have to do is: delete `build` and `.gradle` folder under `android` folder, then run again, it works. Hope it may help someone.

Answer (score 2):

My app kept crashing because I had changed the name of the app in a few places. Make sure your app name is the same everywhere.
Check if the folder name in

```
android/app/src/main/java/com/<appname>
```

has the same name as that of your app in manifest file in

```
android/app/src/main/
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me
run `react-native start --reset-cache`
after this  if app throws some import error kill the task and run `react-native start` or `npm start` normally and open the app.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting my `node_modules`, reinstalling them and run

```
npx react-native run-android
```

fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

While running your Android Emulator for debugging also run

> Android Studio -> Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor

It will tell you exactly what is crashing the app under `LogCat` tab.

Comment: Android Device Monitor was deprecated in Android Studio 3.1 and removed from Android Studio 3.2. The features that you could use through the Android Device Monitor have been replaced by new features.

Answer (score 0):

two easy steps solved my problem...

open android studio and remove offline bundle from src/main/assest..(** if any)
open MainApplication.java and remove the following import..
import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, maybe you made the same mistakes i did.

Make sure u didn't change the app's package name (ex: com.myapp.app).

I lost a lot of time on this. Seems like someone else published a app with the same name on google play, and i didnt change it correctly in each place i should on mine.

Anyway, if that is not your problem, it is probably in something u changed in build.gradle or other config file, try to remember where u last changed something.

Answer (score 0):

Was having this issue on Windows 10

What fixed it for me in the end was:

1. delete `C:\Users\%userprofile%\.gradle\caches`
2. delete`your-react-app/android` folder completely - then 'Discard Changes' in git so you get the original files back
3. re-run `npx react-native start` and `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

A tip, my emulator api version was 32. And my targetSdkVersion was 31.

I created another emulator which api level is 31 and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was a lot. I was using react-native-video then at some point installed react-native-track-player. These packages were supposed to run together on the app. And so it was working fine until I ran into an issue and I needed to clear my build folder.

After clearing it, my app refused to open but was installing.

What I did to fix the issue:

- Clear my node_modules and reinstalled (This did not fix the issue)
- Then I uninstalled **react-native-track-player** and started using **react-native-sound-player**.
- Reinstalled react-native-video and followed the installation guide from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video)
- Cleared my build again and performed all necessary npm installs

In my case, I found that using **react-native-video** and **react-native-track-player** together was the major source of my problem and I think it's related to both packages using different versions of exoplayer. So I would say you uninstall one of them or find a way to work around the exoplayer versions.

Just incase, I was using **react-native-video** version **5.2.1** and **react-native-track-player** version **3.2.0**

Answer (score -1):

a very simple solution for me.
delete this file -> gradle-wrapper.properties
and run android folder with android studio.

Answer (score -1):

In case you tried any of the given suggestions and none worked, use Android Studio to run the app in debug mode and then watch logs at the debug console.

For me, it was a styling rule error. I did
`paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' && 50` which caused the app to exit immediately on Android.

The debug console log I got was `E/unknown:ViewManager: Error while updating prop paddingTop`

To correct that, I did `paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 150 : 0`

Answer (score -1):

Well first of all, does it crashes when it opens or does it crash at a specific screen? Mine crashed because I did not put my text inside `<Text></Text>` inside the `TouchableOpacity`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```html
Delete Your node modules
Then run npm install
after this run
for window 
gradlew clean
for macOS
./gradlew clean
then run
npx react-natie run-android --variant-release
or 
npx react-natie run-android
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).