# My React app is crashing when I pushed to TestFlight with no error messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have developed a shopping application using React and I pushed the app to TestFlight for testing but when I am opening the app is crashing with no error message. When I am running the app on simulator/emulator is running with no issues.

Same applies to Android, when I am creating APK for the app is not running is showing me "App has stopped" and the app is crashing but it showing me a successful build.

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "npx react-native run-android",
    "ios": "npx react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "npx react-native start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cocart/cocart-rest-api": "^1.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.2.6",
    "@niku/react-native-dropdown-select": "^0.1.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.5",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^12.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.1.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.16.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.10.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.5.4",
    "firebase": "^8.6.8",
    "lodash.filter": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-easy-rating": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-fontawesome-pro": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.4",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-material-dropdown-v2": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.9.2",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.0.0",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.13.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-woocommerce-api": "^1.8.8",
    "react-number-format": "^4.6.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.6.3",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

This picture is result of my `logcat`
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The app is running on emulator but it is showing this error:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

````
  <!-- OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS, REMOVE WHATEVER YOU DO NOT NEED -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
  <!-- These require runtime permissions on M -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <!-- END OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS -->
  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  >
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="YOUR-APP-URL-HERE"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="YOUR-APP-SDK-VERSION-HERE"/>
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen"
    >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
  </application>
</manifest>```

This is what is showing me when I ran npx react-native run-android --variant=release

[![enter image description here][3]][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/it16T.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqTYL.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd8Wk.png
````

Comment: Check your expo-updates config that was causing app crash for me, for ios builds

Comment: This is my app.json ```{
  "name": "myapp",
  "displayName": "myapp",
  "expo": {
    "name": "my app",
    "slug": "my app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ]
  }
}```

Comment: Expo managed or bare?

Comment: Could you please clarify more?

Comment: Does your project contain android & ios folders or it is managed by expo?

Comment: It contains Android and iOS folders

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49824865/5532513

Comment: Did the android & ios build worked without crash?

Answer (score 0):

To fix crashes on android & ios do this

To confirm this is the reason run the logcat you should see a error message like this `expo-updates must be configured with a valid update URL or scope key`

For ios

Open `Expo.plist` file & add this to replace it with your OTA URL if you did not configure it or don't want OTA to copy-paste the same thing.

```
<key>EXUpdatesURL</key>
<string>https://example.com</string>
```

For android

In AndroidManifest.xml add the below code.

```
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="YOUR-APP-URL-HERE"/>
<meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="YOUR-APP-SDK-VERSION-HERE"/>
```

Comment: For Android, I already have this code in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Can you share the `AndroidManifest.xml`? Make sure you did `./gradlew clean` before build

Comment: please check the answer. I post it as answer

Comment: Also, when I am trying to build APK for android using this "npx react-native run-android --variant=release" it is showing me build success build when I run the apk on android emulator it is showing your app is stopped

Comment: Keep `logcat` on check properly it is easy to miss the error message.

Comment: Please check the photo I uploaded as an answer

Comment: No, I am talking about the android studio logcat. Open android studio -> open your projects android folder -> run the project. Wait for the gradle to finish, once done at the bottom, you can see the logcat option. Keep the logcat in error mode by default it will be verbose.

Comment: Please check the photo with question that I added which is result of logical

Comment: Clear the log, switch to error mode & reopen the app, once the app crashed check the last part of the log it should have the error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235713/discussion-between-maryna-azeez-and-rajendran-nadar).